# Trigonometric Graphs - Point of intersection with the curve and line

Tags: trigonometry

The diagram shows the graph of y=(a)sin(b)x +(c) .

1)write down the value of a,b and c.

2)Find the coordinate of P an Q, the points of intersection with this curve and the line y=2.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I know the answer to part .1) which is y=4sin(x)-1... But i don't know how to find the answer to part .2)

Comment: Is that the correct answer?

Comment: 4sinx - 1 =2 doesn't hold for x =0 .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $y=4\sin(x)-1$ is the right answer$^1$ to part $1$, we now have to solve

$$4\sin(x)-1=2$$

**Edit**

$$4\sin(x)-1=2 \Longleftrightarrow 4\sin(x)=3 \Longleftrightarrow \sin(x)=\frac34$$

The exact solutions are $x=\arcsin\left(\frac34\right)$ and $x=90^\circ-\arcsin\left(\frac34\right)$ (by symmetry), and the coordinates are $(0.848,2)$ and $(2.294,2)$.

---

$^1$ As you have drawn the graph, it seems as if it passes through $(0,0)$, which $y=4\sin(x)-1$ doesn't. If it passes through $(0,0)$, the graph is $y=4\sin\left(x+\arcsin\left(\frac14\right)\right)-1$.

Comment: How did you get 0.848 and 2.294 as the x coordinates

Comment: @Ali, approximating the exact solutions.

Comment: @Ali, does your textbook agree with you that the solution to part $1$ is $y=4\sin(x)-1$?

Comment: I am not using a textbook for this question, it is from a homework question

Comment: Do you want the curve to pass through $(0,0)$ or not? If not, the solutions are in my answer, if yes, then you have to calculate $4\sin\left(x+\arcsin\left(\frac14\right)\right)-1=2$.

Comment: Your answer i think is right, but could you answer in more detail. I don't understand

Comment: Alright, I will elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

- Setting $x = 0$ gives us $c=0$ (since $a sin(bx) = 0$)
- Maximum value of $asin(bx)$ is attained when sin(bx) is maximum(i.e when $sin(bx)=1$).

  Since maximum of $asin(bx)=3$ from the graph, $a=3$
- Also the maximum occurs at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$. Hence, we have $sin(b*\frac{\pi}{4}) = 1$. This holds for $b = 2$
- By solving $3sin(2x)=2$, and applying the appropriate values of x, we get $x=0.72973$ and $x=1.20593$.

Hence P and Q are $(0.36486, 2)$ and $(1.20593, 2)$ respectively.

Comment: I still feel the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Ali - Is it correct now?

Comment: what i think is that : 4sin(x)-1=2, since y is equal 2, therfore x= shift-sin(3/4) = 48.6, then take this away from 90-48.6, which is equal to 41.4, therfore x = 48.6, and 41.4

Comment: 4sin(x) - 1 = 2 doesn't hold for x = 0